# How to redirect user to component of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I want when a user clicks the "Contact" link in my `NavBar` component to navigate to the home page to the specific Contact component. I tried using React-Router-DOM to navigate user to the component but it removes the rest of the home page and has only the `SettingsPage` component. I want to remain in the same home page.

Using Vite + React and tailwind

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import Mission from './components/Mission';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import ProfilePage from './pages/ProfilePage';
import SettingsPage from './pages/SettingsPage'
import CommingSoon from './pages/ComingSoon';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/SettingsPage" element={<SettingsPage />} />
          <Route path="/Profile" element={<ProfilePage />} /> {/* Add this line for the new page */}
          <Route path="/CommingSoon" element={<CommingSoon />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

HomePage.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Mission from '../components/Mission';
import Contact from '../components/Contact';
import TestComp from '../components/TestComp';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <> 
      {/* Output goes here */}
      <Hero />
      <Mission />
      <TestComp />
      <Contact />  {/* This text on navbar*/}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

NavBar.jsx

```
// src/components/NavBar.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="bg-gray-800 p-4">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between px-10">
        <div className="text-white font-bold text-lg"><Link to={"/CommingSoon"}>Akadimia</Link></div>
        <ul className="flex space-x-5">
          <li className="text-white"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li className="text-white"><Link to="/SettingsPage">Contact</Link></li>  {/* This text on navbar*/}
          <li className="text-white"><Link to="/Profile">Profile</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ID to the container of the component, e.g.:

```
const Contact = () => {
    ...
    return (
        <div id="contact">
            ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

Then you can link to this element by redirecting to "/#contact"

Comment: on app.jsx
<Route path="/#contacts" element={<Contact/>} />
on NavBar.jsx
 <li className="text-white"><Link to="/#contacts">Contact</Link></li>  {/* This text on navbar*/}
when I remove the # it works normal (showing the component without the homepage but when I have # it changes the search bar to ...#contact but nothing happening

Comment: You don't have to define a route for the Contact. Leave everything as it is, just add the id to the container and add the /#contact only for the link (e.g. ```<Link to="/#contact">Contact</Link>```)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code after updating NavBar.jsx and Home.jsx so when the "Contact" link is clicked, it will smoothly scroll to the Contact section on the Home page instead of navigating to a separate page.

**Navbar.jsx:-**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  const scrollToContact = () => {
    const contactSection = document.getElementById('contact-section');
    if (contactSection) {
      contactSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <nav className="bg-gray-800 p-4">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between px-10">
        <div className="text-white font-bold text-lg"><Link to="/">Akadimia</Link></div>
        <ul className="flex space-x-5">
          <li className="text-white"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li className="text-white" onClick={scrollToContact}>Contact</li>
          <li className="text-white"><Link to="/Profile">Profile</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

**Home.jsx:-**

```
import React from 'react';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Mission from '../components/Mission';
import Contact from '../components/Contact';
import TestComp from '../components/TestComp';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Output goes here */}
      <Hero />
      <Mission />
      <TestComp />
      <Contact id="contact-section" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if user is on any route path other than `"/"` where the `Home` component is rendered. I'm sure the OP would like to navigate to the contact component from anywhere in their app. It also relies on the `Contact` component properly handling the passed `id` prop, e.g. passing it through to an actual DOMNode, otherwise there is nothing to select from the document to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The "contact" link rendered by `NavBar` links to the `"/SettingsPage"` route, not the contact section of the home page on `"/"`, so of course the UI is going to remove all of the `Home` component when the new route is rendered.

## Solution

React-Router-DOM alone isn't capable of using hash links to link to a specific section on a specific page. I suggest integrating [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) to allow this behavior. Officially it still only supports React-Router v4/v5, but it works with v6 for basic linking with basic routers such as what you are using.

Example:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="bg-gray-800 p-4">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between px-10">
        <div className="text-white font-bold text-lg">
          <Link to={"/CommingSoon"}>Akadimia</Link>
        </div>
        <ul className="flex space-x-5">
          <li className="text-white">
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>

          {/* Link to the home page, specifically to the contact section */}
          <li className="text-white">
            <HashLink to="/#contact" smooth>Contact</HashLink>
          </li>

          {/* This should be a "Settings" link */}
          <li className="text-white">
            <Link to="/SettingsPage">Settings</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="text-white">
            <Link to="/Profile">Profile</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Add an `id` attribute to a DOM element in the `Contact` component so it's targetable using hash links.

```
const Contact = () => (
  <div id="contact">
    ....
  </div>
);
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-redirect-user-to-component-of-page]